# Primefaces submit ajax request without ViewState when the element is removed too fast

Tags: jsf, primefaces

This is an invalid request (viewstate missing) created by p:schedule element, when the element `homeTabs:widgetContent-LEAVE_CALENDAR:lvCalendarForm:schedule`  is removed too fast (while the schedule's script has not finished):

`javax.faces.partial.ajax: true
javax.faces.source: homeTabs:widgetContent-LEAVE_CALENDAR:lvCalendarForm:schedule
javax.faces.partial.execute: homeTabs:widgetContent-LEAVE_CALENDAR:lvCalendarForm:schedule
javax.faces.partial.render: homeTabs:widgetContent-LEAVE_CALENDAR:lvCalendarForm:schedule
homeTabs:widgetContent-LEAVE_CALENDAR:lvCalendarForm:schedule: homeTabs:widgetContent-LEAVE_CALENDAR:lvCalendarForm:schedule
homeTabs:widgetContent-LEAVE_CALENDAR:lvCalendarForm:schedule_start: 2023-10-30T00:00:00.000Z
homeTabs:widgetContent-LEAVE_CALENDAR:lvCalendarForm:schedule_end: 2023-12-11T00:00:00.000Z`

Does anyone know a solution, I've been wrestling with it for more than a day. Much thanks.

I'm using JSF 2.3, PrimeFaces 8

Comment: Not enough information here. Please create a runnable reproducer if you want help debugging the issue: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces-test

Answer (score 0):

I've found the issue. It's because I put the element inside a nested form. Remove the nested form and everything is okay now.